# MockRetrofit doesn't allow to avoid network error

Tags: mocking, retrofit, retrofit2

I using MockRetrofit(retrofit 2 snapshot 4) to mock the server apis.

```
NetworkBehavior networkBehavior = NetworkBehavior.create();

networkBehavior.setFailurePercent(1);
networkBehavior.setDelay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

MockRetrofit mockRetrofit = new MockRetrofit.Builder(retrofit)
    .networkBehavior(networkBehavior)
    .build();

BehaviorDelegate<FinderCommonApis> delegate = mockRetrofit.create(FinderCommonApis.class);
finderCommonApis = new MockFinderCommonApis(delegate);
```

I am also using this mock in my test cases. My test cases intermittently fail because of the `NetworkBehavior`. It introduces the network error which causes the intermittent failure. I want to completely avoid this network error, but it doesn't look like I can completely avoid it. I even tried to set the failure percentage to 0 but it doesn't allow. So I set the lowest possible value that is 1. They have made `NetworkBehavior` optional in `MockRetrofit.Builder` but it provides its own default `NetworkBehavior` which also introduces same network error. I checked the `NetworkBehavior` code and they have made it final class so I can't override it. I am running out of idea to avoid this problem.

I just wanted to know how to completely avoid the NetworkBehavior.

Answer (score 2):

> I even tried to set the failure percentage to 0 but it doesn't allow.

This is not true. See: https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/78897005be619c3b63d238bf5d0de0f1580d95d4/retrofit-mock/src/main/java/retrofit2/mock/NetworkBehavior.java#L106-L109

0 is a valid value and is what should be used to disable all failure.

Comment: you are right. Some how I mixed -1 and 0. It is working. Thank you for prompt reply